# Onclick: scroll a otra sección de la página y colapsar sidebar

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Al presionar un botón que tiene un Onclick necesito ir a otra sección de la página y una vez que la pagina este lista me colapse el sidebar.

el botón...

```js
function nuevocontrol(){
    window.location.href = "controlEquipos.php";
    $(document).ready(function () { 
    $("body").addClass('sidebar-collapse');
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" sonclick="nuevocontrol()"> Nuevo Control de Equipos<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

Comment: Buenas Jonathan, a ver lo primero. Te he puesto scroll en el titulo porque has puesto sección, pero releyendo, creo que podrías referirte a cambiar de "archivo". Por ejemplo de index.html a contacta.html. Es correcto?

Comment: Por otro lado, puedes colocar la estructura de la página y el sidebar que tienes? como lo "descolapsas",... ?

Comment: El error esta en `sonclick`.. deberìa ser onclick

Comment: @GDP , a ver si me logro explicar mejor. En estoy en el index hago clic en uno de mis vínculos del sidebar y me lleva a la parte del controlEquipos.php si elimino la parte del $(document).ready al presionar el botón "al mismo tiempo" me esta redirigiendo a esta pagina y me colapsa el sidebar, pero como me redirecciona a esta otra parte pero como el sidebar-collapse ya se ejecuto en esta nueva pagina ya no se agrega la clase sidebar-collapse al body.  Dato el el Header y la etiqueta body no está en el controlEquipos.php se carga en el header con un include_once.  espero se entienda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te aconsejaria de pasar algun parametro por `GET` es decir

```
function nuevocontrol(){
    window.location.href = "controlEquipos.php?bar=colapse";
}
```

en la pagina del controlEquipos.php te fijas si tiene el parametro, y en caso le agregas la clase sidebar-collapse con la ayuda de JQuery o Javascript :

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET["bar"]) {
    if($_GET["bar"] == "collapse"){
 ?>
       <script>
          //con JQuery
          $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse"); 
          // con Javascript
          var body = document.getElementByTagName("body");
          body.className = body.className + " sidebar-collapse"; 
       </script>
<?php  
    }
 }
```

esto porque estas cambiando pagina, asi que el pedazo `$(document).ready(...`se ejecuta en el index y no en controlEquipo.php.

espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos

Comment: Muchas gracias...eso me ayudo a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

saludos prueba en este ejemplo te especifican como usarlo 
https://codepen.io/ondrejsvestka/pen/MmOVOw

Answer (score 0):

otro podría ser que tengas unos errores en el código

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="nuevocontrol()"> Nuevo Control de Equipos<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>


  function nuevocontrol(){
window.location.href = "controlEquipos.php";
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $("body").addClass('sidebar-collapse');
});};
```